How to get accent cedilla between z and a?
I am trying to write Krzakala with accent cedilla between z and a as so:

Typing \c{z} does not seem to work. The dashed l through \l works fine.

Where exactly does hat come from? To me this seems to be a z with an inverse cedille (polish, isn't this cedille that points in the other direction) that just looks this way in this font.

Looking at Wikipedia it might be on the a, but badly placed in the font

The name is Krząkała and the image shows a wrong placement of the ogonek that must accompany the a, not be in the middle.
If you don’t know how to directly type the character, use
Krz\k{a}ka\l a

You need \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} anyway. Copy-paste from here, to get correct input.

It worked, thank you. I agree that the image seems wrong. Glad you could point to the correct spelling.
